# What are some computer interfacing electric energy meters on the market?

Tags: electrical, meter

Does computer interfacing electric energy meters exist? With possibilities to get/log current power usage and monthly used kilowatt hours. With ethernet/rs232 etc interface. I am looking for this for European current 3phase, 230V. Looking for affordable options.

Comment: Related question (possible duplicate) http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4247/interfacable-wall-outlet-power-meter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Power Meter](http://www.google.com/powermeter/about/) is one good place to start: [AlertMe](http://www.alertme.com/products/energy) makes a product for the UK market specifically.

It's also possible to DIY. For 3 phase power, you'd need 3 [current transformers](http://www.google.ca/search?q=clamp-on%20current%20meter&qscrl=1), and then something to interface them to (an [arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) may fit the bill). Note, be sure you actually have 3-phase: most residential buildings use split-phase (in which case you only need 2 transformers). On top of the hardware, you'd have to write all the software for logging and viewing the data, or interface into the [Google Powermeter API](http://code.google.com/apis/powermeter/).

There's several projects to look at as well:

- [DIY Interent-connected whole house power monitor](http://www.slashgear.com/diy-internet-connected-whole-house-power-monitor-2231584/)
- [Not so tiny power meter](http://www.billporter.info/not-so-tiny-power-meter/)
- [Arduino Kilowatt meter](http://www.cerebralmeltdown.com/programming_projects/Arduino_Kilowatt_Meter/index.html)

Comment: AFAIK google power meter is dead

Comment: You're right: "We are pleased that PowerMeter helped demonstrate the importance of access to energy information, and created a model for others. We retired the service on September 16, 2011."

Answer (score 1):

You should check KWh meters that support the S0 interface that provides a pulse output. I have something like this http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/125000-149999/125363-an-01-ml-WechselstrZaeh_Geco32_230V32A_LCD_de_en_fr.pdf

i think this one is as well able to do it http://www.iskra-mis.si/catalogue/20071212152244/20071212153441/2008041510314899/

after that you should just follow these steps with arduino http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Main/EEM12L-32AKWhMonitoring

I did it using a data logger shield and then exporting it to excel.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.theenergydetective.com/store/

http://www.etherbee.com/products/ECM1240/packages/plugAndPlay.htm