# Looking for a WATT-O-METER with specific features

Tags: electrical, energy-efficiency, product-review

Recently I bought an [OWL+USB WATT-O-METER](http://www.theowl.com/index.php?page=owl-usb) and got very disappointed. Making a long story short, I'm looking for a device that will give me:

1. accurate readings
2. good software for data management
3. a watt-hour counter for 24 hour cycle - on the display monitor, very important.

I want to know what my electricity consumption is in 24hr without calculating anything, so it should have a feature that shows this information on the monitor.

Can someone recommend a proper device?

Comment: Are you trying to monitor your whole house, or just a single outlet / device?

Comment: Duplicate of http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5381/computer-interfacing-electric-energy-meter

Comment: this isn't a duplicate because i am familiar with the general existence of power meters, but i am looking for specific features and asking if someone has former experience with those kind of devices and know in which i can find what i am looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I personally use an [APC](http://www.apc.com/template/country_selection.cfm?ref_url=/tools/download/index.cfm) with the free management software for my computer...

Most of their [Back-UPS®](http://www.apc.com/products/family/index.cfm?id=29) line of products have the ability to connect to a computer and monitor your input/output power.  Some of them, like the [APC Power-Saving Back-UPS Pro 1300](http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=BR1300G&total_watts=200) that I use, even offer an LCD display to see the current stats without a computer [image: APC LCD monitoring display]. The [computer software these UPSs use](http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=SFPCPE302) is free at no additional cost, so you are only paying for the actual unit.  If you wanted to use this as a whole house solution, there are some detailed solutions out there, such as [this one](http://www.kondra.com/circuit/circuit.html).  It all depends on home much you wish to invest into such a product, and what you intend to accomplish...

Comment: -1, question was for a product recommendation for a whole house device, not a brand recommendation for a specific device. Also, for and product or brand recommendations, make sure to disclose if you have any affiliation to avoid being flagged as spam.

Comment: I have no affiliation, and APC is a whole house option...

Comment: APC is a company, not a product. And for a company, their focus is on computers and data centers. If you edit your answer to reference a product that solves this problem from APC, rather than a generic vendor link, I'll be happy to remove the downvote.