# Do they make AC power meters that measures average, min and max watts used?

Tags: electrical, meter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a wall outlet power meter that I can interface with from a computer?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4247/is-there-a-wall-outlet-power-meter-that-i-can-interface-with-from-a-computer)

Is anyone familiar with an AC power meter that I can get the min, max and average watts used while it is running?  I've seen a few meters for purchase, but they seem to only report the current usage, and don't store any history.

I see this other question [Is there a wall outlet power meter that I can interface with from a computer?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4247/is-there-a-wall-outlet-power-meter-that-i-can-interface-with-from-a-computer) that has one that reports to a computer, so that looks like a viable choice, but if there are any cheaper ones that will give me this information, I'm interested in those as well

Comment: Are you looking to track a single appliance, or the whole house?

Comment: @Tester101 - I'm looking to track a single appliance (a computer), and want to see max and average usage over different workloads, but won't always have access to the machine, so leaning away from the meters that report just the current usage.  Regarding the device in the related question, yes, I would prefer a cheaper device. I don't need the ability to connect to a computer, so figured there might be a device that just did min/max/average over life of it being plugged in (similar to how some $20 digital thermometers work)